# Trying to decode the word "callback" in this node.js code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js and came across this bit of code and am trying to understand what the word "callback" is doing. I mean I know what a callback is, but why are they actually using the word "callback" below and what is it doing. Really appreciate your help.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('nickname', function(data, callback) {
        if (nicknames.indexOf(data) != -1) {
            callback(false);
        } else {
            callback(true);
            nicknames.push(data);
            socket.nickname = data;
            console.log('Nicknames are ' + nicknames);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a variable name.

It's defined in the function expression as an argument: `function (data, callback) {`.

The expectation is that the value passed to it will be a function (hence the function being called here: `callback(false);`).

For a simple example that doesn't depend on any library code you can't see:

```js
function doSomething(callback) {
    alert("doing something");
    callback(1);
}

function myCallback(value) {
  alert("myCallback called with the argument: " + value);
}

doSomething(myCallback);
```

> But function (data, bob) is the callback function. Why include "callback" (or bob) within the callback. Does that make sense?

You have multiple callback functions.

One callback function is passed another function as an argument which it, in turn, calls.

Answer (score 1):

In Node.js, `callback` is the de-facto standard name for callback functions. You could easily call it `bob`, and it would have the same effect:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('nickname', function(data, bob) {
        if (nicknames.indexOf(data) != -1) {
            bob(false);
        } else {
            bob(true);
            nicknames.push(data);
            socket.nickname = data;
            console.log('Nicknames are ' + nicknames);
        }
    });
});
```

As to what it's doing, think of it as an anonymous function that notifies the caller (like a parent function) that the called function is done. A simpler example would be:

Function A calls function B (which takes a long time to run). When B is done, it needs to tell A that it's done:

```
function a() {
    b(someParameter, function(err, data) {
        // function(err, data) is the anonymous function we pass as a parameter to b()
    });
}

function b(someParemeter, callback) {
    // do something that takes a while
    // 'callback' is the variable name for the anonymous function that was passed
    // We execute it using ():
    callback(err, data);
}
```

Comment: But function (data, bob) is the callback function. Why include "callback" (or bob) within the callback. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, was adding some more to the answer. See now.

Comment: No prob! Node's callback syntax can make anyone bug-eyed without much effort ;)

Answer (score 1):

Node.js uses asynchronous callback functions instead of blocking the caller and performing the operation synchronously. `callback` is simply the very common name given to the variable that holds the callback function. I usually name the variable `done` in my own code simply because it is shorter.

Comment: Question: So in my example, the word "callback" holds the outcome of the callback function(data, callback)?

Comment: "callback" represents the callback function itself, and you call it in that context. The outcome could be retrieved by doing ```var outcome = callback()```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is socket.io, that callback is used to respond to a client when the 'nickname' event is triggered.

From [their documentation](http://socket.io/docs/)

> **Sending and getting data (acknowledgements)**
>
> Sometimes, you might want to get a callback when the client confirmed
>   the message reception.
>
> To do this, simply pass a function as the last parameter of .send or
>   .emit. What’s more, when you use .emit, the acknowledgement is done by
>   you, which means you can also pass data along:

Server (app.js)

```
var io = require('socket.io')(80);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('ferret', function (name, fn) {
    fn('woot');
  });
});
```

Client (index.html)

```
<script>
  var socket = io(); // TIP: io() with no args does auto-discovery
  socket.on('connect', function () { // TIP: you can avoid listening on `connect` and listen on events directly too!
    socket.emit('ferret', 'tobi', function (data) {
      console.log(data); // data will be 'woot'
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Question: So regarding my example, callback(false) means the outcome of function(data, callback) is false. Does that sounds right?

Comment: No, it would be undefined since the function doesn't "return" anything. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return 


When callback is executed, the library is likely sending a message back to the web client with the value "true" or "false".